# Responsiveslides transition looks strange

Tags: jquery, css

I have included a responsiveslides slide show with the standard settings direct from the web page. It works but the transition looks very strange. The image fills the whole width of the screen before taking the correct size. I also get the "li-dot" on all images exept the first one. This is probably connected to CSS but I can't find a way to correct it. Any help on this issue will be appreciated.

Code excerpt

```
<%@ Page Title="XXX" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script src="Scripts/responsiveslides.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
    });
</script>
<div>
   <ul class="rslides">
    <li><img src="Images/Slides/SAMS-1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Slides/SAMS-2.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Slides/SAMS-3.png" /></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*! http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */


.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }


.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }


.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }


.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

Comment: No code provided, no help...

Comment: Ok, I have now completed my question with some code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/aLy2D/1/ (with pager and nav options) and everything is working properly (well, i guess so...).

Actually, i saw a typo in your css code, maybe your problem comes from here :

```
*! http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */

// Multiline comment should start with /*
/* http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */
```

And if you want to show the pager, you have to set an option :

```
$(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    pager: true
});
```

Full documentation is available here : http://responsiveslides.com/

EDIT : i updated the fiddle with a document.ready method